# Error 500 with django 1.6 app running on apache 2.4 and python 3.3 with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

For the past months I've been coding a django-app for my current employer and they now want to deploy it to the server. I know there have been a lot of threads regarding this problem but none of them helped me solving this.

I'm using Python 3.3 with Django 1.6 and mod_wsgi on a Windows 7 PC. The server is a Apache 2.4 via XAMPP.

Over the last couple of days I tried to publish my app to the server but it didn't work. I think I made some progress, going from a non-functional server over a "Access denied" error to the current state where I get a server error 500. I feel like getting really close, however I'm totally stuck now and need some help.

This is part of  my httpd.conf:

```
WSGIPythonPath "C:/TSDE_Workarea/Kmg1yh/SharCC/Workspaces/ReservationTool/PythonReDesign/trunk"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/TSDE_Workarea/Kmg1yh/SharCC/Workspaces/ReservationTool/PythonReDesign/trunk"
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/TSDE_Workarea/Kmg1yh/SharCC/Workspaces/ReservationTool/PythonReDesign/trunk/PythonReDesign/wsgi.py"

<Directory "C:/TSDE_Workarea/Kmg1yh/SharCC/Workspaces/ReservationTool/PythonReDesign/trunk/PythonReDesign">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        #Require all granted
    </Files>
    DirectoryIndex wsgi.py
</Directory>
```

My wsgi.py looks like this (Just the basic one that django creates when starting a new project. I tried adding new paths to wsgi.py but it didn't change anything.):

```
"""
WSGI config for PythonReDesign project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os, sys
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "PythonReDesign.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Now when I start my server and try to access the page, I get the infamous 500 error. The apache error log gives me the following errors:

```
[Fri Jan 10 15:08:40.017397 2014] [:error] [pid 6676:tid 1876] [client 127.0.0.1:61162] mod_wsgi (pid=6676): Target WSGI script 'C:/TSDE_Workarea/Kmg1yh/SharCC/Workspaces/ReservationTool/PythonReDesign/trunk/PythonReDesign/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Jan 10 15:08:40.017397 2014] [:error] [pid 6676:tid 1876] [client 127.0.0.1:61162] mod_wsgi (pid=6676): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/TSDE_Workarea/Kmg1yh/SharCC/Workspaces/ReservationTool/PythonReDesign/trunk/PythonReDesign/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jan 10 15:08:40.017397 2014] [:error] [pid 6676:tid 1876] [client 127.0.0.1:61162] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Fri Jan 10 15:08:40.017397 2014] [:error] [pid 6676:tid 1876] [client 127.0.0.1:61162]   File "C:/TSDE_Workarea/Kmg1yh/SharCC/Workspaces/ReservationTool/PythonReDesign/trunk/PythonReDesign/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>\r
[Fri Jan 10 15:08:40.017397 2014] [:error] [pid 6676:tid 1876] [client 127.0.0.1:61162]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application\r
[Fri Jan 10 15:08:40.017397 2014] [:error] [pid 6676:tid 1876] [client 127.0.0.1:61162] ImportError: No module named 'django'\r
```

I'm really stuck here and it's driving me nuts. Any help will be greatly apprecciated! Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Errorlog when omitting PythonHome:

```
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683] mod_wsgi (pid=5288): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/TSDE_Workarea/Kmg1yh/SharCC/Workspaces/ReservationTool/PythonReDesign/trunk/PythonReDesign/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 339, in urlconf_module\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]     return self._urlconf_module\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683] AttributeError: 'RegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_urlconf_module'\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683] \r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683] \r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 101, in get_response\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 318, in resolve\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]     for pattern in self.url_patterns:\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 346, in url_patterns\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 341, in urlconf_module\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "C:\\Python33\\Lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1584, in _gcd_import\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 584, in _check_name_wrapper\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1022, in load_module\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1003, in load_module\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_for_loader_wrapper\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 868, in _load_module\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "C:\\TSDE_Workarea\\Kmg1yh\\SharCC\\Workspaces\\ReservationTool\\PythonReDesign\\trunk\\PythonReDesign\\urls.py", line 6, in <module>\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]     from PythonReDesign.views import *\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "C:\\TSDE_Workarea\\Kmg1yh\\SharCC\\Workspaces\\ReservationTool\\PythonReDesign\\trunk\\PythonReDesign\\views.py", line 9, in <module>\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]     import PythonReDesign.commons as com\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683] ImportError: No module named 'PythonReDesign.commons'\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683] \r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683] \r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\wsgi.py", line 206, in __call__\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]     response = self.get_response(request)\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 196, in get_response\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 231, in handle_uncaught_exception\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]     return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\views\\debug.py", line 69, in technical_500_response\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]     html = reporter.get_traceback_html()\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\views\\debug.py", line 323, in get_traceback_html\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]     c = Context(self.get_traceback_data())\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\views\\debug.py", line 281, in get_traceback_data\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]     frames = self.get_traceback_frames()\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\views\\debug.py", line 428, in get_traceback_frames\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]     pre_context_lineno, pre_context, context_line, post_context = self._get_lines_from_file(filename, lineno, 7, loader, module_name)\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\views\\debug.py", line 379, in _get_lines_from_file\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]     source = loader.get_source(module_name)\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 605, in _requires_frozen_wrapper\r
[Fri Jan 10 16:23:06.296711 2014] [:error] [pid 5288:tid 1868] [client 127.0.0.1:61683] ImportError: importlib._bootstrap is not a frozen module\r
```

Comment: which editor do you use?

Comment: Eclipse for the project itself and notepad++ for viewing the error log.

Comment: Why are you setting WSGIPythonHome? Looks suspiciously wrong. Is that actually the top of a virtual environment for Python 3.3? Also, is your mod_wsgi even compiled for Python 3.3?

Comment: To be honest: I saw it in a different thread where somebody else had the same problem and it greatly reduced the thrown errors. I downloaded a compiled version of mod_wsgi from their website. If I use a different version which is not compatible with Python 3.3 the server doesn't even start, so I think it should be the correct one.

Comment: What version of mod_wsgi are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.4 for Apache 2.4

Comment: OK, good. That's the right version to use. Now what happens if you ommit the WSGIPythonHome line?

Comment: I added the errorlog to my original post. When I run the command, nothing is displayed.

Comment: Great! Even if there's still a problem, if you change something and the error changes too then that's progress. Are you sure you have a module named commons.py inside PythonReDesign?

Comment: Wow, that actually was the mistake. I tried to import a package which I deleted weeks ago. I feel incredibly dumb right now haha. The site works now although the styles are not applied, but I try to solve that now. Thank you all very much!

Comment: Don't. Deployment is a headache. I added an answer with an explanation why WSGIPythonHome was the problem

Comment: You need to serve the [static files through your server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files). add this line to the http.conf: `Alias /static/ /path/to/mysite.com/static/`

Comment: Works. Awesome. Thanks again, really helping me out here! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you don't have the site-packages on your PATH. Let's look at the line WSGIPythonHome. [According to the mod_wsgi documentation](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonHome), this configuration directive is used for (emphasis mine):

> Used to indicate to Python when it is initialised where its **library**
>    **files are installed**. This should be defined where the Python
>   executable is not in the PATH of the user that Apache runs as, or
>   where a system has multiple versions of Python installed in different
>   locations in the file system, especially different installations of
>   the same major/minor version, and the installation that Apache finds
>   in its PATH is not the desired on

In other words, it's good if your server has multiple python installations and you're afraid it will get them mixed up. But as you mentioned in part of your comments, you're not using a virtualenv. So there's no need to use that directive. With it, what you're actually doing is misdirecting apache to look for python libraries in the wrong location, meaning it doesn't find the module django. Removing it solves that problem

As for the second problem that occured, it will probably take some digging, because it seems to be related to your own models, and is probably unrelated to apache. Running the devserver helps find those out and dealing with them easier. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing \r at the end of your lines in wsgi.py with \n? There is no problem with your apache and mod_wsgi setup. You can enable viewing of all the whitespace characters if you are using notepad++.

Comment: In wsgi.py they are formatted as \n. That's at least what notepad++ tells me when I enable viewing all characters and look for the\n expression. Doesn't give me any results when searching for \r though.

Comment: the traceback clearle shows \r at the end of from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application. BTW, do you have django installed on your server?

Comment: Yes, that also confuses me. The apache is currently running on my local machine where django is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message says that it cannot find `django`, I suspect that this is a virtualenv problem. Have you installed django inside a virtual environment?

If so, please ensure that the site-packages are in your path as well [as mentioned in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-a-virtualenv).

Comment: I'm not using virtualenv so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Could you still try adding the site-packages in your python path?